# Issue with field separator in AWK script

Tags: awk

Having a very large file where two lines shown below and having two fields name and revision having colon delimiter. I need to print only the second column.

```
sam:7.[0:6]
Ram:8.[6:6]_rev[2:4] h_ack[2:6]
vincent:58
```

I tried this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F: '{print $2}'

7.[0
8.[6
58

Output should be:
7.[0:6]
8.[6:6]_rev[2:4] h_ack[2:6]
58
```

What went wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your `awk` expression is that you are splitting on all `:`.
Instead, you want to split only on the first `:` from the start.

```
$ awk -F'^[^:]+:' '{print $2}' file
```

The regex pattern matches the start of the string `^`, any character other than a `:`, and finally a `:`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Could you please clarify? Make sure the question contains all information needed for us to help you

Comment: @Ramkumar My code provides exactly the desired output. Have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you specify *field separator* as `:`, it's normal behavior of `awk` to output this, ex:

`7.[0`, because you need the other columns after `$2`.

`cut` here, better suits the requirement:

```
cut -d: -f2- file
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/:.*/){
  print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: above one is working .. but how can I ignore the : (colon)deli metre in between brackets []

Comment: @Ramkumar, you mean you want to remove `:` in between `[` but your sample output doesn't show like that please confirm the same once?

Comment: @Ramkumar, Could you please do lemme know on this one?